# C++ Linking Problem with CURL, OpenSSL and AWS SDK S3 using conan, cmake

Tags: curl, cmake, openssl, libcrypto, aws-sdk-cpp

I am having trouble in linking two libraries, CURL, OpenSSL and AWS SDK S3, simultaneously. But the thing is I need to manage another libraries with conan 2.0.

I shrinked CMakeLists.txt and Example source code as much as possible.

## [Environment]

1. Two Conan Dependencies, `openssl/3.1.4`, and `libcurl/8.4.0`
2. I already installed aws-sdk-cpp-s3 manually on my computer by reading [official tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup-linux.html). (And of course, I did `make install`.)

### Project structure

```bash
$ tree
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeUserPresets.json
├── conanfile.txt
├── include
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── src
    └── main.cc
```

### conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
openssl/3.1.4
libcurl/8.4.0

[tool_requires]
cmake/3.27.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(AWSS3Test VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS s3)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cc
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    CURL::libcurl
    OpenSSL::Crypto
    ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES}
)
```

### main.cc

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

#include <openssl/hmac.h>

#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.h>

int main() {
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Debug;

    Aws::InitAPI(options);
    int result = 0;
    {
        Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
        clientConfig.endpointOverride = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX";
        clientConfig.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTP;
        clientConfig.verifySSL = false;

        Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
        credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId("____________");
        credentials.SetAWSSecretKey("_____________________");

        Aws::S3::S3Client client = Aws::S3::S3Client(credentials, clientConfig, Aws::Client::AWSAuthV4Signer::PayloadSigningPolicy::Never, false);
        auto outcome = client.ListBuckets();
        if (outcome.IsSuccess()) {
            std::cout << "SUCCESS!" << std::endl;
            for (auto&& b : outcome.GetResult().GetBuckets()) {
                std::cout << b.GetName() << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::string errorMsg("Failed with error: " + outcome.GetError().GetMessage());
            std::cerr << errorMsg << std::endl;
        }
    }
    ShutdownAPI(options);
}
```

### How did I build?

```bash
$ conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing -s compiler.libcxx="libstdc++11"
$ cd build/
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$ cmake --build . --parallel 9
$ ./AWSS3Test
```

## [Problem]

```bash
$ ./AWSS3Test 
s2n_init() failed: 402653268 (The libcrypto major version number seen at compile-time is different from the major version number seen at run-time)
Fatal error condition occurred in /root/awsbuild/aws-sdk-cpp/crt/aws-crt-cpp/crt/aws-c-io/source/s2n/s2n_tls_channel_handler.c:203: 0 && "s2n_init() failed"
Exiting Application
################################################################################
Stack trace:
################################################################################
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(aws_backtrace_print+0x98) [0x7f4e1801115d]
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(aws_fatal_assert+0x5b) [0x7f4e17ffb557]
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(aws_tls_init_static_state+0x18c) [0x7f4e17e09e39]
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(aws_io_library_init+0x63) [0x7f4e17dfd378]
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(aws_mqtt_library_init+0x2d) [0x7f4e17d7d62a]
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(_ZN3Aws3Crt9ApiHandleC2EP13aws_allocator+0x58) [0x7f4e17d5aac6]
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(_ZN3Aws3NewINS_3Crt9ApiHandleEJP13aws_allocatorEEEPT_PKcDpOT0_+0x56) [0x7f4e17c50b45]
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(_ZN3Aws13InitializeCrtEv+0x27) [0x7f4e17c5078f]
/usr/local/lib64/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so(_ZN3Aws7InitAPIERKNS_10SDKOptionsE+0x12e) [0x7f4e17c4c859]
./AWSS3Test() [0x43c650]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe5) [0x7f4e165f1d85]
./AWSS3Test() [0x43c95e]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can see it said `The libcrypto major version number seen at compile-time is different from the major version number seen at run-time`.

## What I did for solve this problem

I thought that the library who is using `libcrypto` are two. CURL and OpenSSL. So, I remove `CURL::libcurl` on `target_link_libraries` in `CMakeLists.txt`. And It works.

### After change, it works.

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    # CURL::libcurl
    OpenSSL::Crypto
    ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES}
)
```

```
$ ./AWSS3Test
SUCCESS!
```

However, I need `CURL` library for another function. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure that CURL and OpenSSL libraries which you use are linked with the same version of `libcrypto` library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Would you please HOW can I make sure both are linking same version?

Comment: I think I found the reason is that, AWS SDK C++ S3 on my computer was installed with openssl-devel, whose version is 1.1.1k, and project was built with openssl version 3.1.4. Of course, both installing aws sdk c++ s3 and building project, need libcrypto. However, as error message said, version is different. One is 1.1.1k and the other is 3.1.4. In conclusion, I removed CURL, OpenSSL on conan dependency and installed `-devel` on my computer for linking not conan but my computer.